# Trying to get one cell's values with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to get a single cell of values from MySQLdb, in Python. Here's my code:

```
fname = c.execute("""SELECT fname from employees WHERE user = %s;""", (useruname))
```

However what I get is "1L", which is not what I want - fname should contain a string, not a long integer.

Why would it do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The method [`execute`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute) "returns long integer rows affected, if any".

To get the value of fname, you need to fetch the results using for example [`fetchall`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.CursorStoreResultMixIn-class.html#fetchall) or [`fetchone`](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.CursorStoreResultMixIn-class.html#fetchone):

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT fname from employees WHERE user = %s""", (useruname,))
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row[0]
```